# If $|f''(x)|<1 $ then show that $|f'(x)|<1$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $ f$ defined on $[0,1 ]$ be a twice differentiable function such that, $| f'' (x) | < 1$ for all $x \in [0,1 ]$. If $f (0) = f (1)$, then show that, $| f' (x) | < 1$ for all $x \in [0,1]$
As $f(0)=f(1)$ is given I used Rolle's theorem. But it gave me just the following
$f'(c)=0$

Comment: What can you say about $\lvert f'(x) - f'(c)\rvert$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Indeed, the first step is to notice that $f'(c) = 0$ for some $c$.  Now, use the mean-value theorem on $f'$.  Find a bound for $|f'(c) -  f'(x)|$ given any $x \in [0,1]$.

Comment: Will you please explain in some greater detail ?

Comment: What does the mean value theorem state? Apply it to $f'$.

Comment: Why $f'(c) = 0$?

Comment: forget about it. I thought you mean for all c, $f′(c)=0$.